# Migrating from RaisedButton to ElevatedButton

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I'm new to Dart & flutter and need some help with Migrating from RaisedButton to ElevatedButton.
How does the styling code for the elevatedButton of this RaisedButton look like?

```
child: RaisedButton.icon(
          icon: Padding(
            padding: options.iconPadding ?? EdgeInsets.zero,
            child: icon ??
                FaIcon(
                  iconData,
                  size: options.iconSize,
                  color: options.iconColor ?? options.textStyle.color,
                ),
          ),
          label: textWidget,
          onPressed: onPressed,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(options.borderRadius),
            side: options.borderSide ?? BorderSide.none,
          ),
          color: options.color,
          colorBrightness: ThemeData.estimateBrightnessForColor(options.color),
          textColor: options.textStyle.color,
          disabledColor: options.disabledColor,
          disabledTextColor: options.disabledTextColor,
          elevation: options.elevation,
          splashColor: options.splashColor,
        ),
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `ElevatedButton` `style` property like so:

```
ElevatedButton.icon(
      icon: Padding(
        padding: options.iconPadding ?? EdgeInsets.zero,
        child: icon ??
            FaIcon(
              iconData,
              size: options.iconSize,
              color: options.iconColor ?? options.textStyle.color,
            ),
      ),
      label: textWidget,
      onPressed: onPressed,
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        primary: options.color,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(options.borderRadius),
          side: options.borderSide ?? BorderSide.none,
        ),
        textStyle: TextStyle(color: options.textStyle.color),
        elevation: options.elevation,
        // and so on 
      ),
    );
```